# Strategy for lazy-loading tab content in a TabSheet in Vaadin 7

Tags: java, tabs, lazy-loading, vaadin, vaadin7

I am looking for a way to load content into a tab on a Vaadin TabSheet only after the tab is select rather than before. [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), is the term.

Lazy loading of a Vaadin 7 [Tabsheet](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html) is not obvious as the content of each tab is required at the time of construction.

I read the thread, [Strategy for creating lazy load tabs](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/269264), on the Vaadin forums. I did learn from [Jens Jansson](https://vaadin.com/web/peppe/home) that on the client-side, Vaadin is already lazy-loading. The DOM is not populated in the browser until the tab is selected. But I am concerned about easing the load on the server-side. That thread does not solve that problem.

Comment: Put dummy panel in it, and catch TabSelected event (or so) to build real view

Answer (score 5):

Here is one full example. It could be encapsulated in a dedicated class later. Note that the selected tab content changes each time its selected. If you need lazy loading but doesn't need refreshing each time, I would create a boolean loaded field and make the refresh dependent on it. Counter intuitively you can make the tab eager by supplying eager constructor argument. It is useful for the first shown tab for example.

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet;
import com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;


public class TablesFrame extends CustomComponent {
private static class LazyTabChangeListener implements SelectedTabChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void selectedTabChange(SelectedTabChangeEvent event) {
        LazyTab tab = (LazyTab) event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab();
        tab.refresh();
    }
}


private abstract class LazyTab extends CustomComponent {
    public LazyTab() {
        this(false);
    }


    public LazyTab(boolean eager) {
        if (eager) {
            refresh();
        }
    }


    abstract Component build();


    public final void refresh() {
        setCompositionRoot(build());
    }
}

private LazyTab tab1 = new LazyTab(true) {
    @Override
    Component build() {
        return new TextField("1");
    };
};

private LazyTab tab2 = new LazyTab() {
    @Override
    Component build() {
        return new TextField("2");
    };
};


public TablesFrame() {
    TabSheet ts = new TabSheet();
    ts.addSelectedTabChangeListener(new LazyTabChangeListener());
    ts.addTab(tab1, "Tab1");
    ts.addTab(tab2, "Tab2");
    setCompositionRoot(ts);
}
}
```

**UPDATE** It's also possible to subclass TabSheet. This way you can use regular tabs too and have all the operations of the TabSheet. Note that eager LazyTabs and regular tabs are different here, becouse LazyTabs will reload.

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet;


public class LazyTabSheet extends TabSheet {

public LazyTabSheet() {
    addSelectedTabChangeListener(new LazyTabChangeListener());
}


public static abstract class LazyTab extends CustomComponent {
    public LazyTab() {
        this(false);
    }


    public LazyTab(boolean eager) {
        if (eager) {
            refresh();
        }
    }


    public abstract Component build();


    public final void refresh() {
        setCompositionRoot(build());
    }
}


private static class LazyTabChangeListener implements SelectedTabChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void selectedTabChange(SelectedTabChangeEvent event) {
        Component selectedTab = event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab();
        if (selectedTab instanceof LazyTab) {
            ((LazyTab) selectedTab).refresh();
        }
    }
}

}
```

If you want to use accordion the same way, I wouldn't subclass tabsheet but implement the functionality via decorator pattern. Accordion subclasses TabSheet so it should be managable.

Comment: Why extend `CustomComponent`? Why not subclass `TabSheet`?

Comment: Does it matter for a quick example? It's not my production ready code, but a quick way to help someone. Tailor the code for yourself or ignore it, your call.

Comment: Not a criticism, a serious question. I'm not clear about the purpose of CustomComponent. I wondered it it would be possible/advisable to take your approach by subclassing TabSheet.

Comment: See update (edited before your comment :P). No particular reason for avoiding inheritance here. It just happened I wrote the sample this way. Thinking through it its better to  subclass tabsheet so you can use regular tabs too and have all the operations of the TabSheet. Note that eager LazyTabs and regular tabs are different here, becouse LazyTabs will reload.

Comment: For a side note: if you want to use accordion the same way, I wouldn't subclass tabsheet but implement the functionality via decorator pattern. Accordion subclasses TabSheet so it should be managable.

Comment: Awesome answer. I wanted to add that your LazyTab could also be an interface. That way it would be up on every tab themselves to implement it, but it would allow the tab itself to extend what ever it likes, like VerticalLayout, CustomComponent or CssLayout.

Also, in the class where you have the tabsheet, you can have references to the tabs themselves and sometimes it is easier to play quick'n'dirty and just take care of all the logic within selectedTabChange. You can put a temporary component into the tab, like CssLayout, and then init the real view and switch it out in selectedTabChange.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation compiling some of the suggestions above:

```
public abstract class LazyTab {

    Component comp;
    private boolean eager;
    private boolean cached;

    public static LazyTab of(boolean eager, boolean cached, Supplier<Component> componentSupplier) {

        return new LazyTab(eager, cached) {

            @Override
            protected Component build() {
                return componentSupplier.get();
            }
        };
    }

    protected LazyTab(boolean eager, boolean cached) {

        this.eager  = eager;
        this.cached = cached;

        if (eager) comp = build();
    }

    protected abstract Component build();


    public final void refresh() {
        if ((comp == null) ||!cached) comp = build();
    }

    /**
     * @return get component on demand (depends on eager and cached properties)
     */
    public final Component getComponent() {
        return comp;
    }


    public static class LazyTabSheet extends TabSheet {

        public LazyTabSheet() {
            addSelectedTabChangeListener(new LazyTabChangeListener());
        }
    }

    public static class LazyTabChangeListener implements TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void selectedTabChange(TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeEvent event) {

            Component selectedTab = event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab();

            if (selectedTab instanceof LazyTab) {
                ((LazyTab) selectedTab).refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```